# Hashed password to mail server to login

Tags: encryption, jakarta-mail, bcrypt

I stored the email's password in the database by using Bcrypt and since hash function is only one-way it's not possible to retrieve the plain-password to send to the mail server to log in. So what are the best options to store the password in the database so that I can retrieve it?

Comment: The best option is not to store the password in your database. Store the user's contact details instead. If the user forgets the password, send a password reset link so they can choose a new one.

Comment: yeah but I'm creating an invoice maker program and one of its features is that the user can send an invoice via mail; so how can I store user's mail and password?

Comment: Don't use their mail provider, use your own and send an email on their behalf.